# Query a database in Django and not creating a db

Tags: python, django, database

Am I able to query a database I have in place with Django and not creating a database? I ask this question because all documentation I have read shows Django as creating a database. I do not want to create a DB, but use a DB I have in place in my Django apps. I have read through the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/), Google searches, and YouTube but I am unable to find anything further on not creating a DB and only using a DB I have in place.

Comment: can you be a little clear about what you want? and if you dont mind please post some relevant code pictures or something so that we can understand

Comment: You missed [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/) in the docs specifically dedicated to that exact issue.

Comment: Django will not create any database on its own. You have to create migrations for that. There is also the `managed` attribute to exclude a model from migrations explicitly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: @Daniel Thank you. I am unsure how I missed that page within Django doc's.  By reading the documentation, I assume all I need is db name and fields within a legacy db. This helps out greatly. Thank you again.
Exprator sorry I did not supply any code. I did not start any coding until I knew 100% I was able to query & use a legacy db. As I start coding a dashboard, I will share how the coding is going and hopefully it may help someone after me.
Klaus thank you. That is correct, but I was looking for querying a legacy table. I miss worded what I was looking to accomplish.